# Send password. Urlencoded or multipart?

Tags: forms, security, ssl, https, passwords

I have set up TLS to transfer passwords securely. Now I wonder if it is overkill to use form (POST) with enctype = "urlencoded" as also a layer of "protection"? (I know anyone can decode this). The other option is POST with enctype = "multipart" which is transparent / readable directly.

Appreciate all points of view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encoding in this case is not a security feature (ie. it has nothing to do with security). It doesn't matter how you encode the password, the only purpose of such encoding is to be able to transmit it in a valid HTTP request, considering all the special characters it may have and so on. Security (encryption, server authentication, etc) is provided by TLS under HTTP.